# How to specify the sender with the alpine e-mail client?

Tags: command-line, users, configuration, email, alpine-mail

I seem to have run into a situation where [configuring](https://askubuntu.com/q/1335222/847449) the `alpine` e-mail client (formerly just `pine`) for a specific user seems to override some configuration so that the username for the operating system account is used from within `alpine` to determine who the e-mail is from.

Why is this happening, generally?

How is the sender explicitly configured?

Answer (score 0):

as here:

https://askubuntu.com/q/1350439/847449

from:

https://groups.google.com/g/comp.mail.pine/c/3s0mVilxiPE/m/kQYg2Z09BAAJ

it looks like the solution is to use a role as per:

http://www.ii.com/internet/messaging/pine/changing_from/

which I'll have to look into further.  Thanks to usenet `comp.mail.pine`.

I'll update the answer, this is just links to general info and a how-to guide.